# Delete files before last revision

Tags: vbscript

In one folder I have 10000 files and the the names of files is structured  like this:

```
File1_0, File1_1, File1_2, File1_3
File2_0, File2_1, File2_2
File3_0, File3_1, File3_2, File3_3
...
File1000_0, File1000_1
```

I like to delete previous revisions of the files and to stay with the last one. Above files to become like this:

```
File1_3
File2_2
File3_3
....
File1000_1
```

I am trying the following: Put the name without `_xx` in an array then to remove the duplicates. But I don't think this is correct and for the moment I am stuck in the logic of the way I should do this.

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, folder, sourcefolder, file
Dim b : b = Array()
Dim i
Dim x
Dim z
Dim y

sourcefolder = "C:\test"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sourcefolder)
i = 0

For Each file In folder.Files
    i = i + 1
    x = fso.GetBaseName(file)
    ReDim Preserve b(UBound(b) + 1) : b(UBound(b)) = Left(x, Len(x)-2)
    y = y & b(i-1) & "@"
Next

z = RemoveDuplicates(y)

For i=0 To UBound(z)-1
    WScript.Echo i+1 & "           " & z(i)
Next

Function RemoveDuplicates(str)
    Dim d
    Dim elem
    If Trim(str) = "" Then
        RemoveDuplicates = Array()
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'make dictionary case-insensitive

    For Each elem In Split(str, "@")
        d(elem) = True
    Next

    RemoveDuplicates = d.Keys
End Function
```

Comment: So you've posted some code, but what is the actual problem?

Comment: After removing names from array how I rebuild the names with the last revision and the delet the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach your problem is to build a dictionary that maps the basenames of the files to the highest revision number:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(sourcefolder)
    basename = fso.GetBaseName(f.Name)
    a = Split(basename, "_")
    revision = Int(a(UBound(a)))
    prefix   = a(0)
    if d(prefix) < revision Then
        d(prefix) = revision
    End If
Next
```

Then run a second loop to remove all files whose basename doesn't have that revision:

```
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(sourcefolder)
    basename = fso.GetBaseName(f.Name)
    a = Split(basename, "_")
    revision = Int(a(UBound(a)))
    prefix   = a(0)
    If d.Exists(prefix) And revision < d(prefix) Then
        f.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Note that this code assumes that the underscore separating prefix and revision is the only one in the basename. If you have filenames containing more than one underscore (like `foo_bar_1.txt`) you'll need to adjust the extraction of prefix and revision to take care of that.

---

With that said, I ***strongly*** recommend against doing revision management in filenames. Use a revision control system (Git, Mercurial, Subversion, ...). That's what they were invented for.

Comment: Ansgar, thanks for your sugestion! (But for the moment I am the end user so an revision control system it is overkill). Some how, your code is not working on my machine (probably it is me)

Comment: "The code is not working" is not a problem description. How do you expect me to debug that? I'm not sitting in front of your computer. Also, no, setting up an RCS is not overkill, even if you are the only user.

Comment: Sorry for this, I was trying to say, that, your code is running without any error but it is not deleting anything. I do not have an debuging/programing tools (I can not install anything on this machine) to tell exact what will be the problem I just use in notepade - `WScript.Echo` etc ...But this line  `d.Exists(basename) And revision < d(basename)` is not acting correct.

Comment: @white_flag My bad. The keys of the dictionary must be the prefix part of the basename, not the entire basename. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

' Folder to process
Dim sourceFolder
    sourceFolder = "."

Dim fso
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Regular expresion used to separate base name and sequence  
Dim re 
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "^(.*)_([0-9]+)$"

' Dictionary to store data for each sequence
Dim fileSequences
    Set fileSequences = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' fileSequences will use the base name of the files as key and 
    ' hold as data an array with the higher sequence number and the
    ' associated file full path.

Dim f, colMatches, baseName, sequence    

    For Each f In fso.GetFolder(sourceFolder).Files
        ' Try to separate base name and sequence
        Set colMatches = re.Execute( fso.GetBaseName(f.Name) )
        ' Only handle serialized files, those whose name match the regular expresion
        If colMatches.Count > 0 Then 
            ' base name and sequence are stored in the Submatches collection
            ' file extension is included in the base name to avoid handling separate series as one
            baseName = LCase( colMatches.Item(0).SubMatches(0) & "." & fso.GetExtensionName( f.Name ) ) 
            ' Get the numeric sequence value - This should also handle zero prefixed sequence numbers
            sequence = CLng( colMatches.Item(0).SubMatches(1) )

            Select Case True
                Case Not fileSequences.Exists( baseName )
                    ' New sequence found - store current sequence value and the associated file path
                    fileSequences.Add baseName, Array( sequence, f.Path )

                Case sequence < fileSequences.Item( baseName )(0)
                    ' File with a lower sequence number found - Remove
                    f.Delete

                Case sequence > fileSequences.Item( baseName )(0)
                    ' File with a higher sequence number found - Remove previous one
                    fso.DeleteFile fileSequences.Item( baseName )(1)
                    ' Update sequence information with new higher value and the associated file path
                    fileSequences.Item(baseName) = Array( sequence, f.Path )
            End Select

        End If 
    Next
```